# NullPointerException In Ecclipse Android Sdk Unfortunately myapp has stopped

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, emulation, runtimeexception

I am a beginner. Stuck on this NullPointerException. This is a simple program of buttons. As soon as i run as android application, the project opens and immediately gets closed by displaying unfortunately my app has stopped.

```
04-15 17:40:05.656: D/AndroidRuntime(599): Shutting down VM
04-15 17:40:05.656: W/dalvikvm(599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2adcd58)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599): Process: com.example.buttona, PID: 599
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buttona/com.example.buttona.Buttonwa}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at com.example.buttona.Buttonwa.onCreate(Buttonwa.java:29)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
04-15 17:40:05.666: E/AndroidRuntime(599):  ... 11 more
04-15 17:40:11.466: I/Process(599): Sending signal. PID: 599 SIG: 9
04-15 17:57:32.017: D/AndroidRuntime(662): Shutting down VM
04-15 17:57:32.017: W/dalvikvm(662): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2adcd58)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662): Process: com.example.buttona, PID: 662
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.buttona/com.example.buttona.Buttonwa}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.example.buttona.Buttonwa.onCreate(Buttonwa.java:29)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
04-15 17:57:32.027: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  ... 11 more
04-15 17:57:34.957: I/Process(662): Sending signal. PID: 662 SIG: 9
```

This Is The Java File.

```
public class Buttonwa extends Activity {

Button name, surname;
TextView display;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttonwa);

    name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name_button);
    surname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.surname_button);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            display.setText("Your Name Is Shashank Yadav");

        }
    });

    surname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            display.setText("Your Name Is Yadav Shashank");

        }
    });
```

this is the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.buttona.Buttonwa$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
     />
<Button 
android:id="@+id/name_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:text="@string/Name"
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/surname_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/name_button"
android:text="@string/Surname"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Either put all the views into `activity_main.xml` or change your code so all the view inflation happens in `onCreateView()` of your Fragment

Comment: sorry, please be more specific. Ken Wolf.

Comment: (1) Are you sure that "activity_buttonwa.xml" is the name of the layout file you provided in your question? If so, and you have multiple variants of it, make sure they all have the IDs your need. (2) Also, please indicate which line in your code snippet is line 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have created View elements in your fragment `fragment_main.xml` (I assume that's what it's called, you haven't posted the name) but your code expects them in your activity.

When you do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_buttonwa);

name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name_button);
surname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.surname_button);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
```

You are saying, "Hey activity, check `activity_buttonwa.xml` for all these view elements, you'll find them there.

Judging from your error message, `name` is `null` and therefore you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you try and set an `OnClickListener` on it. It's `null` because it's not in your `activity_buttonwa.xml` file.

To fix, you can **either** move all that xml into `activity_buttonwa.xml` **or** you can move the inflation code into your fragment:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        name = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_button);
        surname = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surname_button);
        display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.display);

        // Add OnClickListeners, etc.

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I would say it's better to move the inflation code to your fragment, as above.

Comment: Thanks Ken Wolf. Actually I have been referring to Youtube tutorials which are quite old.