# Erroring out as java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

New to Android and Java. Was following an example. Erroring out with following log:

```
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.onCreate(CrazyTipCalc.java:57)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-19 02:05:25.920: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  ... 11 more
```

**CrazyTipCalc.java**

```
package com.example.crazytipcalc;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.os.Build;

public class CrazyTipCalc extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
    private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
    private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

    private double billBeforeTip;
    private double tipAmount;
    private double finalBill;

    EditText billBeforeTipET;
    EditText tipAmountET;
    EditText finalBillET;

    SeekBar tipSeekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            //      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            billBeforeTip = 0.00;
            tipAmount = 0.00;
            finalBill = 0.00;
        } else {
            billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
            tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
            finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);
        }

        billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
        tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
        finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);

        tipSeekBar = (SeekBar)  findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);
        tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);

        billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListner);
    }

    private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListner = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            try {
                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(arg0.toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                billBeforeTip = 0.00;
            }
            updateTipAndFinalBill();
        }

    };

    private void updateTipAndFinalBill(){
        double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
        double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip * tipAmount);
        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
    }

    protected void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);

    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tipAmount = (tipSeekBar.getProgress()) * .01;
            tipAmountET.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));
            updateTipAndFinalBill();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_tip_calc, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crazy_tip_calc,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_crazy_tip_calc.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="@string/bill_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billEditText"
        android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/final_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changeTipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/billTextView"
        android:text="@string/change_tip_text_view" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/changeTipSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/billEditText"
        android:progress="15" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what is the line no: 57?

Comment: You are mixing up your fragment XML with your activity XML. You have posted fragment xml but you are trying to inflate it in your activity code. It's a common problem. See a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23092206/833647

Comment: your layout is not same, seek bar is not exists on `activity_crazy_tip_calc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);
```

But your views are in `fragment_crazy_tip_calc.xml`. SO your initialization fails leading to `NullPointerException`.

You need to change to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_crazy_tip_calc)
// you also have the fragment code. so instead of this i recommend the below
```

Or

Move initialization of views to Fragment's onCreateView and also move the related code

```
   EditText billBeforeTipET;
   EditText tipAmountET;
   EditText finalBillET; 
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crazy_tip_calc,
                container, false);
           billBeforeTipET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
           tipAmountET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
           finalBillET = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);
           tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.changeTipSeekBar);
        return rootView;
    }
```

You also need to uncomment the below

```
   // getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
   //      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the mentioned in the current view hierarchy. The views belong to the fragment layout not the activity. SO you need to use the infalted view object to initialize your views.

Comment: little slow. My Simulator is little slow. I have uncommented as well

Comment: @user1509593 so what happens. It should not crash now

Comment: Hang on. It is still crashing

Comment: @user1509593 post the updated code and the stacktrace. Crash is bcoz of a different reason

Comment: My runcat.log has disappeared. The Android Simulator just glows. I dont see the crazy calculator work yet. I am looking it in eclipse menu options

Comment: @user1509593 no idea about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51005/discussion-between-user1509593-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

you are initilizing wrong xml file:

change it like below:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_crazy_tip_calc);
```